# Sizing table view cell with 2 prototype cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view that has 2 prototype cells.

One prototype cell is sized dynamically since it depends on how much content is in a label. The other prototype cell will always be the same size.

I currently have it working so that the dynamic prototype cell sizes perfectly and adjusts its height as needed, but the static prototype cell is all scruntched up in a very small cell.

How can I size both so that the correct size is used to display the content properly?

Comment: You are using the constraints on both cells?

Comment: the constraints on the dynamic cell set the height, but for the static cell I have constraints set but just want it to be a static height

Comment: So, set height constraint. Please, post your constraints (storyboard or code).

Comment: a height constraint on the cell? or the content

Comment: On cell. Inside cell you have your `UIView` (label, button...).

Comment: You can also try to specify and estimatedItem size. If it can not set up the auto layout constraints it will fall back to the specified height

Comment: I have auto size and auto estimate

Comment: @DisplayName - even if your "static prototype cell" is, well, static, it should still have proper constraints. In other words, if "CellA" has a multi-line label for variable text, and "CellB" has a single-line label, set up the same constraints. You don't need to treat them differently. If the "static" cell is being *scruntched up* then the constraints are not set correctly.